# build API upon existing API

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have several controllers in my application that the only purpose is to send specific data that is taken from the MongoDB for my views, and I created a little plugin to not have to use every time that ugly and unreadable mongoose code in all controllers that i need access the db and take something:

```
MyModel.find (_id: req.params.id, etc ....
```

So I created this plugin that uses Promises. This is an example code:

```
 database.GET({
   model: someModel,
   sort: 'something',
   limit: {},
   options: {}
 }).then(function (result) {
   res.json(result);
 }).then(undefined, function (error) {
   console.log('Error: ' + error);
 });
```

My question about this is simple: Is this stupid? I made this thinking about organization and not performance..

I've done courses of all kinds, and most teachers always taught to care for the readability of the code ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfectly valid way of making things simpler in your application.  If you're using a decent promises library (I understand that [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) is a top contender) you shouldn't lose anything on the performance front.

All API's are implemented in terms of other API's.  It's API's all the way down....

(The exceptions aren't particularly notable.)

Comment: Do make sure that your syntax and semantics are correct, of course.